# Split one column into 2 columns based on the last character of the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `region_no` in a table. The column can hold 2 kinds of values - one set of values that end with the letter 'R' and the other that end with letter 'B'. This column must be split into 2 columns based on the last letter.

The create table and insert of sample data is :

```
CREATE TABLE test_17Jan
(
    Region_No varchar(8), 
    Customer_Name varchar(20), 
    City varchar(20), 
    zip_code varchar(10) 
)

INSERT INTO test_17Jan VALUES ('101R', 'John Doe', 'Detroit', '48127')
INSERT INTO test_17Jan VALUES ('202B', 'John Doe', 'Detroit', '48127')
INSERT INTO test_17Jan VALUES ('201B', 'Tim Smith', 'Waunakee', '53597')
```

The desired output is :

| Customer_Name | City | zip_code | Inside_Sales_Region | B2B_Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Detroit | 48127 | 101R | 202B |
| Tim Smith | Waunakee | 53597 | NULL | 201B |

I thought of pivot function, but that needs to have an aggregate. Is there a way to get the output in the above format? Any help will be appreciated. The code will run on SQL Server 2019 (v15).

Comment: Yes, you will need to aggregate. `PIVOT` or conditional aggregation is exactly what you want and need.

Comment: The problem here is you're expecting to match up the `John Doe` customer based mainly on name. That rarely works out well. You will have a **MUCH** easier time with this if the column is instead of a foreign key to match the primary key of a hypothetical "Customers" table. That would also then be the better way to pull in the City and Zip information.

Comment: I totally agree with your PoV Joel. Unfortunately we get this information from another vendor who share a csv file. Some of these customers do not exist in the application DB to get their Id. Thats why the reps in the respective region must reach out to these customers. But to identify which rep should reach out to the customer we use the zip code data shared by customer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get your desired results:

```
select Customer_Name, City, zip_code,
  Max(Inside_Sales_Region) Inside_Sales_Region,
  Max(B2B_Region) B2B_Region
from (
  select Customer_Name, City, zip_code,
    case when Right(Region_No,1) = 'R' then Region_No end Inside_Sales_Region,
    case when Right(Region_No,1) = 'B' then Region_No end B2B_Region
  from test_17Jan
)t
group by Customer_Name, City, zip_code;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.  I marked it as answer and also voted it.

Answer (score -3):

better option should be LEFT SELF JOIN. But this should also work.

```sql
SELECT 
CUSTOMER_NAME, CITY, ZIP_CODE,
CASE
    WHEN Region_No like '%R' THEN Region_No
    ELSE NULL AS Inside_Sales_Region,
CASE
    WHEN Region_No like '%B' THEN Region_No
    ELSE NULL AS B2B_Region

FROM test_17Jan;
```

Comment: This won't result in the result set the OP is after. For starters it'll result in 3 rows, not 2.